# ng-bind-html cannot detect directive as attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-bing-html to show content in html.

```
<div ng-repeat="object in question">
   <div class="row">
      <div ng-bind-html="showComponent(object)"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In JS part:

```
$scope.showComponent = (object) ->

        if typeof object.type == 'undefined'
            width = object.position[1]
            offset = object.position[2]

            content = object[$scope.lang]
            console.log(typeof content)
            return '<div lvldraggable="true"' + '>' + content + '</div>'
```

In js **lvldraggable** is an attribute defined in the directive:

```
app.directive 'lvldraggable', ['$rootScope','uuid', ($rootScope, uuid)->
    restrict: 'A'
    replace: true
    link: (scope, el, attrs, controller) ->
        id = angular.element(el).attr("id")
        unless id
            id = uuid.new()
            angular.element(el).attr("id", id)

        el.bind "dragstart", (e)->
            e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', id)
            $rootScope.$emit("LVL-DRAG-START")

        el.bind "dragend", (e)->
            $rootScope.$emit("LVL-DRAG-END")
]
```

**But in the front end, lvldraggable attribute cannot be detected and translated in html. 
How should I fix that?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, this is correct, `ng-bind-html` will **not** recognize directives.  It is for static html.  If you search SO, there are plenty of questions about this. [Here is one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723305/using-directive-in-ng-bind-html)

Comment: @DavinTryon Hi, thanks, so how should I resolve this problem

Comment: This is a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723305/using-directive-in-ng-bind-html

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular ng-bind-html-unsafe and directive within it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-unsafe-and-directive-within-it)

Comment: @DavinTryon thanks, so I should add compile in directive or in the showComponent?

Comment: You really should be using `ng-include` instead of what you are doing.  `ng-bind-html` is really to be used for pre-rendered static html coming from the server. `ng-include` compiles for you automatically.  You can then add optional templates using `ng-switch` or `ng-if`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51964/discussion-between-ivy-and-davin-tryon)

Comment: Hi @Justin, i am facing the same issue. Do you find any solution? If yes, then please post the same.